# Using CCScrollView for vertical scrolling

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way how we can use CCScrollView for vertical scrolling .. ? 
I am trying to use it, And I am not able to make it scroll in vertical direction.

Please help me with some ideas or tutorials on how to use CCScrollView for scrolling vertically .. ? Or any other way by which a vertical scroll can be achieved in Cocos2d.. ?

Thanks for your time..!!

Comment: why not try the UIScrollView or a library of it, just suggesting.

Comment: Dint gave out a try.. But i think mixing UIKit and Cocos2d will make complications ..! :(

Comment: just use UIScrollView... set proper content size to scroll vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the work around.. THanks @Superman: I looked into mixing UIKit with Cocos2d and I found  [THIS](http://goaheadwithiphonetech.blogspot.in/2012/01/implement-uitableview-in-cocos2d.html), It helped me. !!

I hope It helps anyone looking out for the same :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CCScrollView *scrollView=CCScrollView::create(CCSizeMake(screenSize.width,screenSize.height));
scrollView->setContentSize(CCSizeMake(screenSize.width,screenSize.height-header->getContentSize().height));
scrollView->setPosition(ccp(0,0));
scrollView->setDirection(kCCScrollViewDirectionVertical);
this->addChild(scrollView,0);
```